# Objective c Check when HLS has stopped streaming

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection, http-live-streaming

How can I check when a HLS has stopped streaming?

My code:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue new] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
 {
     NSHTTPURLResponse *tempResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;

     if (error || [tempResponse statusCode] != 200)
     {
         //the video has stopped, do my stuff
     }
 }];
```

The current problem is even the video has clearly stopped streaming, the video player has also completely stopped. It still returns me a statusCode = 200 which telling me that the video is still playing. How to implement it with a correct and accurate way?
Thanks

Comment: The HTTP status code has nothing to do with whether the video is playing or not. Parse the HLS playlist.

Comment: Can you elaborate your suggestion? If status code has nothing to with it then what might be the correct way?

Comment: As I said, parse the HLS playlist data you get from the server there. That will tell you what's happening in the stream.

Answer (score 0):

When you do your request you get the HLS playlist. The server status code doesn't mean anything since it is just the HTTP status code and you will get a playlist successfully regardless of the playback status, at least for some time.

The HLS playlist will contain the end marker if the streaming has ended:

```
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

More information can be found from [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2288/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012238-CH1-TNTAG3).

Do note that the playlist will tell you if the *streaming* end has finished, not if the playback has stopped. There may be lots of video in the list still and the only way to know if *playback* has stopped is to ask the component doing the playback.

Comment: "The HLS playlist will contain the end marker if the streaming has ended", how can I check for this? "EXT-X-ENDLIST" where will this be returned?

Comment: @bubibu Still in the data you're downloading in your code

Comment: #EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1, BANDWIDTH=722000, This is what the data returned to me, I could not find #EXT-X-ENDLIST

Comment: If that's the only thing there then there is no stream